# Why we just can't download a jar file of Javadocs of SWT from the main website

Tags: eclipse, swt, javadoc

For almost every library I've come to see a link of the JAVADOCS jar to be downloaded, plain and simple. Why There is no jar for SWT ? and if there is why it's not on their website ..

Please note that I know there is a version in Eclipse help, and there is an online version, which I can't link to cause It doesn't validate cause it's in php ! no Index.html found

Though that's not what I'm looking for I tried it, I'm using SWT.jar and I want to attach the javadocs jar to it so when CTRL+Space and highlight a method I just see the docs right away beside etc you know..

Anyway Because I think SWT is so great I feel like there is a simple way to do that and I just can't see it maybe. if there is nothing I think I should file a feature request or somethin' to them.

Comment: You can achieve the same thing if you link the source attachment, which you can get from the Eclipse SDK, in the plugins directory - e.g. "org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86.source_3.4.1.v3452b.jar"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I kinda knew this question was not going to get much interest, so I gave it another try and I came back cause I don't want anyone to waste 1 hour of trying to figure out something like that..

1. Download the swt zip
2. Go to eclipse and load existing project
3. you'll find src.zip in that project
4. unzip src.zip and copy the folder "org" org\eclipse\swt..
5. paste that folder in src (inside the project)
6. select org folder in eclipse then go to project >> generate javadocs
7. If you're in windows you probably going to press on (Configure) to pick up the Javadoc.exe file it's in the C:\programFiles\java\jdk-xyz\bin\
8. choose where you want to drop the doc files, next then finish
9. ok, just go to the files and zip it, P.S zip the files don't zip the folder which contains the files cause when you load the docs as archive and validate it won't see the index.html

if you want to know how to load the archive, google it's in (in project properties>> java buildpath >> libraries tab >> swt jar >> add jar >> add your SWT.jar then expand and edit the javadoc location..

That was Robo detailed I know, I just don't want someone to read this and still can't do it

Comment: @SamithaChathuranga it's the source file of swt project

Answer (score 2):

The suggested way to develop SWT apps is by following the instructions at [Developing SWT applications using Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/eclipse.php).  Each download page of eclipse includes an SWT section with SWT source complete zips.

The second way as mentioned is to look in your `eclipse/plugins` directory and use the 2 arch compatible jars provided there:

- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.7.0.v3735b.jar
- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64.source_3.7.0.v3735b.jar

The source jar can be attached so as to provide javadoc.  The javadoc (for most of the API shipped with eclipse) is stored in the `eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv_3.7.0.v20110602-0800.jar` jar.  If you unzip that, it should be in `reference/api`

I know that Eclipse is setting up a maven repository, although a quick scan for **org.eclipse.swt** only found 3.6.2 binaries and source.  See http://maven.eclipse.org.  They're still in they trail phase.